# Como checar se a mensagem foi entregue, websocket php

Tags: php, websocket

Como posso checar se uma mensagem que é enviada pelo Servidor WEBSOCKETS foi entregue ao ponto final?

Uso esta classe: https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat/blob/master/class.PHPWebSocket.php

Comment: Olha a grosso modo, fazendo uma programação lá no "ponto final", caso necessário faça uma outra programação partindo de lá para um banco de dados onde será registrado o evento, existem N maneiras de se garantir isso

Comment: Dou ou não dou os 50?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A classe tem algumas previsões para falha: o método wsSendClientMessage desta classe retorna false se nem todo o conteúdo pôde ser mandado, e a clase fica "pingando" os clientes periodicamente para detectar um cliente travado ou desconectado.

Se você precisa ter certeza imediata que o cliente recebeu e entendeu a mensagem, faça o cliente mandar uma mensagem de confirmação. Mesmo que fosse um framework tipo Socket.IO, que faz reconexão e retransmissão automáticas, uma confirmação positiva é a melhor forma.

Comment: Pode espalmar essas previsões ? Estou a usar estar classe em grande escala futuramente e não gostaria de ter erros graves. Sobre a solução da questão eu acabei por ir nesse caminho mesmo, obrigado!

Comment: Sim, se você olhar o código do método wsSendClientMessage, pode ver que ele manda a mensagem em pedaços, e só retorna true depois do último pedaço ter sido enviado (mas nada garante que ele seja recebido do outro lado, os dados ficam "voando" na rede por um curto intervalo de tempo).  O método wsCheckIdleClients() verifica clientes que não mandaram mensagem nem responderam ao ping, e desconecta quem está há tempo demais fora do ar.

Comment: Mas isso no seu ponto de vista é improdutivo ? Por que ?

Comment: Não, a classe está cumprindo a obrigação dela, que é detectar desconexão, até porque seu código pode pegar este gancho para reconectar, mas não resolve por si só o problema imposto pela pergunta.